# No Touchpad Settings - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

Please take a look at [this article from PCWorld](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3199486/software-productivity/windows-10-how-to-customize-multi-finger-touchpad-gestures.html), and view the screenshots, Windows 10 provides so many customization for the Touchpad, but on my laptop I don't have those options, here's a screenshot of System Settings -> Touchpad:

Win10 Touchpad:  [image: Win10 Touchpad]

And I believe that's because I'm using Asus drivers for the Touchpad, I have this program on my Windows 10, the problem is, it doesn't provide customization as it should, enabling Microsoft gesture (as shown below) doesn't help getting the settings in System Settings -> Touchpad.

Asus Touchpad:  [image: Asus Touchpad]

Here's a screenshot of Device Manager, as you can see, Asus driver is installed, I tried replacing it with HID-compliant device, but it made Touchpad to stop working.

Touchpad Device Manager:  [image: Touchpad Device Manager]

If I uncheck Show compatible Hardware, I get a list of different manufacturers, I tried to see if Microsoft is providing drivers but it's not.

So question is, how can I install an appropriate driver from the list, or download the driver from the internet to get those awesome settings in System Settings?

Manufacturer of my Touchpad:

Elan:  [image: Elan]

Comment: article doesn’t apply to your Touchpad

Comment: @Ramhound But, I should be able to choose to open Cortana OR Notifications panel with three finger tap, and currently it opens Cortana and I want to change it to Notifications, I don't know how I can do that. Is there really no way to customize touchpad settings? on Ubuntu I installed libinput-gestures which would offer lots and lots of customizations, I don't know how to do that on Windows.

Comment: The article is specifically with regards to certain Touchpad components.  With your device your limited to the options the ASUS software offer

Comment: Precision Touchpads: https://www.howtogeek.com/286905/what-is-a-precision-touchpad-on-windows-pcs/ if you were to provide specifics (in other words the exact touchpad you have) I will submit an answer

Comment: @Ramhound Ahh.. it all makes sense now, thanks a lot for the link. I think some time ago I knew the manufacturer of my touchpad, I'm not sure if it was Elan or Synaptics, but I'll google a way to find out the manufacturer

Comment: @Ramhound yep, it's Elan, updated the question with necessary screenshot :)

Comment: You can try using Elan Percision Touchpad driver meant for another device:  https://m.windowscentral.com/how-enable-precision-touchpad-drivers but I suspect Windows would already be using the driver if it was compatible. If it works I will submit an answer

Comment: @Ramhound I completely removed Asus Smart Gesture and tried both `16.11.3.2` and `16.21.13.3` Elan drivers and both didn't work unfortunately, I wish there's some other way..

Comment: Well then your hardware isn’t a precision Touchpad.